# raabitmq consumers built on php-amqplib stops working

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

the rabbitmq or phpampqlib does not through any timeout exceptions and rabbimq dashboard shows  consumers and producers are still intact but the messages are not processed. (my rabbitmq server is on one machine and consumers and producers are in another machine)

keepalive is true and heartbeat is 0 in my case and the php-amqplib version is 3.1.0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.